# Windows 10 Updated - Now PDFTK batch file broken

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, pdftk

I have a batch file that runs a simple "burst" (a.k.a. split) multi-page PDF into single pages scripts, then moves them to a mapped network drive (Z:\).  This batch file is triggered by the user and has been working without a hitch for at least two years.  Last week, there was a flurry of Windows 10 (x64) updates and it stopped working.  Now, instead of looping over every PDF in the source dir, the batch file will generate single pages for the first PDF in the iteration, then stops (although not showing any errors in output).  I have tried a multitude of fixes, including using a full timestamp in the target file names to prevent overwriting, though I don't think that's the problem.  It seems too coincidental that it just stopped working shortly after the updates (per my User). I'm not very experienced with batch files, and just drew this up based on a PDFTK example I saw.  Here it is (not sure why line 2 is being split in the markup, but in the batch file lines 2 & 3 here represent a single line; PS the last line is also being weird, should read: del "C:\Users\My User\Desktop\PHYS_SRCDIR'BACKSLASH''STAR''DOT''STAR'" /F /Q):

```
cd C:\Users\My User\Desktop\PHYS_SRCDIR
for /r %%i in (*.pdf) do (pdftk "%%i" burst output "Z:\PHYSICALS_IN\%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_%%~ni_%%03d.pdf")
del Z:\PHYSICALS_IN\doc_data.txt /F /Q
del "C:\Users\My User\Desktop\PHYS_SRCDIR\*.*" /F /Q
```

Comment: Don't forget to ask your question.

Comment: Sorry, I guess my question is: "How do I make the batch file work again?" and/or "Why is the job/for-loop dying after a single iteration when dozens of PDFs remain in the source folder?"  I've also tried rolling back the "optional" updates, to no avail.

Comment: First, check if your `date` format has changed. Second, check if `Z:` is properly connected

Comment: @Stephan Just checked it on the trouble machine, date format is "Tue 06/15/2021" (minus quotes) as per usual.  I have the users keep their mapped network drives open (and minimized) at all times because if they don't, ever since we switched to windows 10 the mapping gets "dropped" somehow if not constantly open (separate issue).  Regardless, the same behavior on this machine happened when I tried: Local instead of Network folders; Removing all spaces from PDF filenames; Removing all spaces from Directory Path (dir names); Removing all parentheses and brackets from filenames; Using UNC paths.

Comment: Any ideas, anyone?  I'm banging my head against the wall here, it's been working for 2 years (+), no matter how many multi-page PDFs were in the source dir.  Now, if for instance I have a 3-pager PDF called AAAA.pdf (so-named so it will be the first iteration guaranteed, but with other multi-page PDFs in the source dir), I get (let's say I use: "%%~ni_%%03d.pdf" as a format option): AAAA_001.pdf, AAAA_002.pdf, AAAA_003.pdf, doc_data.txt (obligatory PDFTK output), and then the batch job dies.  Just wanted to make sure the issue is clear, looking forward to more ideas, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any new responses lately, and have to divert my attention elsewhere, so my solution was simply to move the batch file to the server w/ "Z:" on it (allowing a limited login to the User), reverse it so it copies from User's PC mapped drive to the Server, and move on to the bigger fish I have to fry.  I know, it's not really a solution but that is my circumstance.  I'll check in from time to time to see if there are any other suggestions.  Since the batch file works perfectly from a WS2012R2 box my only thoughts are that something in Windows 10 "broke" either PDFTK Server or batch files/command-line in general.  Since it works singly and only breaks when trying to loop over several multi-page PDFs, I'm leaning toward batch files/CLI.  Thanks for the suggestions, keep 'em coming!

Comment: Microsoft makes a big point to not break existing scripts. There were huge expansions by jumping from DOS (command.com, up to Win98) to Windows Command Line (cmd.exe) and some tiny improvements since then. None of them broke any batch scripts (old MS-DOS scripts still run, as long as they don't try to access any hardware directly, which Windows prevents. There are no such commands in your script). So I very much doubt it's a "Win10" or "update related" problem. `cd`, `for` (and `del`) didn't change recently, as far as I know. I don't know about the third-party application `pdftk` though.